# how can get date in netbeans?

Tags: java, date, netbeans

please see follow pic.

[image]

[enter link description here](http://mehdi9torki.persiangig.com/image/calender.jpg)

i want when i click on bottom that specified by green circle a thing like that specified by red circle is shown is appeared.

i want two know is there any function or class in java that do that and return

the selected date.

```
i want to use it in mysql.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a `Swing Date Picker`, if I understand correctly. Googling for these keywords turned up the following solutions:

- [JCalendar](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/index.html)
- [DatePicker](http://sourceforge.net/projects/datepicker/)
- [JDatePicker](http://www.jdatepicker.com/)
- [Swing Calendar Component](http://www.calendarcomponent.com/)

Comment: Also consider the following component: http://jdatepicker.org which is open source, unlike the "JDatePicker.com" link provided above.

Answer (score 0):

And if u want this in some web-application go for javascript datepickers. But, if its swing; JCalendar is perfect.